# Time Difference in Flutter (Dart)

Tags: android, date, flutter, dart, time

I have an Api call. I  want to call the Api again when 24 hours passed from the previous Api call. How to find the time difference in flutter. please explain your answer in detail.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does Dart have a scheduler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15848214/does-dart-have-a-scheduler)

Answer (score 3):

**Support:**

Official docs https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html

```
var berlinWallFell = new DateTime.utc(1989, DateTime.november, 9);
var dDay = new DateTime.utc(1944, DateTime.june, 6);

Duration difference = berlinWallFell.difference(dDay);
assert(difference.inDays == 16592);
```

Duration has more properties and methods to check more details.
Duration docs https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.8.3/dart-core/Duration-class.html

**Example: (Edit)**

Save date time in SharedPreferences on API call

```
sharedPrefs.putInt('apiCallTime',DateTime.now().milliSecondsSinceEpoch);
```

When you want to recall the API, get time and call

```
int lastCallTimeInSeconds = sharedPrefs.getInt('apiCallTime')??DateTime.now().milliSecondsSinceEpoch;
DateTime lastCallTime = DateTime.fromMilliSecondsSinceEpoch(lastCallTimeInSeconds);
if(DateTime.now().difference(lastCallTime).inHours>=24){
//Re call API here...
}
```